# Is there any api available to resize the viewport in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension similar to chrome developer console responsive design view. I analyzed available chrome extensions, they are using "Popup" model to achieve that.

[image]

And some extensions are embedding the website into the Iframe to modify the viewport.

I am looking for a chrome extension api to change the viewport like the one above in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pure JavaScript to achieve that?

```
var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', ANY_VALUE_YOU_WANT);
```